# Django apps throw ImportError on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm deploying a Django application to Heroku. This application runs locally, and was built as a structural clone of [django-vue-template](https://github.com/gtalarico/django-vue-template). The only notable changes being:

1. I have more apps in my project.
2. I do not use a settings package with prod/dev modules, just single module.

**File structure:**

[image]

The error I get in the build log throws an ImportError on 'users', but its not app-specific, its whatever app is the first Django app in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

       PYTHONPATH:  .

       BASE_DIR /tmp/build_1803d0c0cef716d3bc64a04ddb7b7ea0/backend

       Traceback (most recent call last):

         File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>

           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line

           utility.execute()

         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute

           django.setup()

         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup

           apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate

           app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create

           module = import_module(entry)

         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module

           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'

 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

       See traceback above for details.

       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.

       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:

          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

 !     Push failed
```

Here is my `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py for reference.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',

    'users',
    'channels',
    'socials',
]
```

I do not get this error locally, even when running `python manage.py collectstatic` so I have a feeling it has to do with my `PYTHONPATH` on Heroku, but I've compared with deploying the unaltered **django-vue-template** & `PYTHONPATH` appears to be the same.

What I can conclude:

- settings.py is being reached
- INSTALLED_APPS are fine up until the actual Django apps
- It doesn't seem like a direct structural error since its unimpacted locally, only when serving `wsgi.py`

If there is more information worth sharing for help debugging, please leave a comment and I'll add it!

---

Update: I realized I was a bit nested which Heroku didn't like. `backend` was just a directory, not a package, so I added `__init__.py` which revealed a greater issue with nesting this way. I've modified my structure to better mirror structure of `backend` in [django-vue-template](https://github.com/gtalarico/django-vue-template/tree/master/backend), so my new structure looks as follows, which again, works locally, but fails with an ImportError on `users` when deploying to Heroku.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution will be very niche for users cloning the django-vue-template, but I'll share instead of deleting the question.

The issue is that django-vue-template doesn't follow the standard Django project structure. Whether or not this is a breaking issue is yet to be determined, but I assume the breaking away from traditional structure was solely to make manageability better when using Vue & Django together.

A few things to note:

1. `manage.py` is in the root of the project, not the root of the Django project.
2. In `manage.py` we need to be sure we're pointing to the explicit settings module. In their project, they use a package with dev/prod modules respectively, but for mine, I use a single module. This module would be `api.settings` not `settings`.
3. Considering the structure, Heroku is correct from perspective of the wsgi module. `users` does not exist, but what does exist is `api.users`, so my installed apps now prefix with `api.`.
4. When importing Django modules like `models` it now needs to be `api.users.models` because of the "breakout" flow of this structure.

Adding these prefixes to accommodate the structural changes fixed this for me, and ultimately I see why they went this route, because build scripts can then be conjoined. Surely there's a way to make these imports a bit less involved for scalability, but for sake of making things work, this is the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue for some heroku apps. This worked for me, run the following commands:

1.disable the collectstatic during a deploy

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

2.deploy

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the underlying issue, it just ignores the command that identifies the error. If `collectstatic` can't run because of an ImportError, then the path will still be an issue when actually serving the wsgi application. `collectstatic` failing is just an entry point to a larger issue.